# Is there any basic Typescript JSX Type definition for HTMLElements?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsx, typescript-typings, web-component

I am currently using a web component in Typescript/JSX that does not come with Typescript declarations (I'm rather new to TS and JSX).
But instead of using the documented `[elemName: string]: any;` for my components:

```js
declare global { 
    namespace JSX { 
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            [elemName: string]: any;
        } 
    }
};
```

Or an adjusted version:

```js
interface IntrinsicElements {
    "my-external-component": {[attribute: string]: any};
}
```

I would love to have a rather specific common HTMLElement type that is intersected like this:

```js
interface MyExternalComponent {
    "api-key": string
}

declare global { 
    namespace JSX { 
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            "my-external-component": MyExternalComponent & BaseHTMLElement;
        } 
    } 
};
```

Which then describes and provides all official HTMLElement attributes as key value pairs.
Does anything like `BaseHTMLElement` exist or do I have to define it myself from scratch, as I've seen it inside other libraries? Or is there any rather generic declaration inside any existing library, that I could reuse without bringing in library-specific stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this ?

```js
interface MyExternalComponent {
  "api-key": string
}


class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyExternalComponent & React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        /* ... */
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Without any framework (like React, Vue, ...):

```js
interface MyExternalComponent {
  "api-key": string
}

declare global { 
  namespace JSX { 
      interface IntrinsicElements {
          "my-external-component": MyExternalComponent & HTMLElement;
      } 
  } 
};
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, but not coupled to React, but free of any framework or library, so I can attach it to any random web component, that does not come with typings. (if that makes sense)

Comment: I tried the HTMLElement version, but it expects me to define 500 attributes since they are not optional. This at least works so far `"my-external-component": MyExternalComponent & React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>;` but still has the React dependency, not sure if this is even bad. Maybe someone is able to tell me what makes sense :D